# Actions vs. CRUD in REST

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

Is it appropriate to perform actions with REST, other than simple create (POST), read (GET), update (PUT), and delete (DELETE)? I'm kind of new to the whole RESTful theology, so bear with me, but how should I accomplish the following:

- I have a web service that needs to talk to another web service. Web service A needs to "reserve" an object on Web service B. This object has a timeout of validity, but can be deleted immediately if need be. It's essentially a glorified permissions system which requires web services to reserve a space on web service B before taking any actions.

My initial thought was to 1. enable authentication of some sort, 2. in the serverside response to a GET call, reserve the space and return the result, and 3. provide immediate "unreservation" of the object via a DELETE call. Is this still being RESTful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's OK to perform actions with rest. What matters is that these actions should be guided by the representations you exchange.

If you think about the way the web works (via a browser), you do this all the time: you get an HTML form that lets you choose a number of actions you can perform. Then, you submit the form (typically via `POST`) and the action is performed.

It's good to be able to use `DELETE` via a programmatic client (which is something that non-AJAX requests in browsers wouldn't support), but the overall approach of a RESTful system should be very similar to what you find for websites (i.e. the focus should be on the representations: the equivalent of web pages in your system).

`GET` shouldn't have side effects, so don't use `GET` to make the reservation itself, use something like `POST` instead.

Comment: It doesn't have to be form-compliant, so should I prefer a `PUT` to a `POST`?

Comment: The purpose of `PUT` is to store the entire representation you send in that resource ([see RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6)). This is probably not what you're doing here. There's nothing wrong with `POST`: http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post

Comment: PUT is fine as long as the operation is idempotent.  In other words, if you create a reservation, and that reservation is somehow unique, then PUT is not appropriate.  However, if you make a reservation and calling the service again would just make the same reservation (similar to an update) then a PUT is appropriate (though not required - POST is still fine if it's more convenient for some reason such as doing from a browser form).  PUT MUST be idempotent.  POST makes no guarantees about idempotency.

Answer (score 2):

#### No - unlikely to be restful

From your description ...

**2. in the serverside response to a GET call, reserve the space and return the result**

GETs should be idempotent. For this reason alone, your service is unlikely to be restful because the state of the system after the first GET is different.

You really need to consider that a **Reservation is a resource** and should be created with a POST to a reservations container which will return the URI of the new resource in the Location header of the HTTP response. This UrI can be used by Get to return the resource and updated with a PUT

**Post should be used to extend an existing resource and Put for replacing the state of a resource.** In your case, consider the Post to be updating a list of Reservations and returning the URI of the new resource (not just the I'd). Put can be used for changing the state associated with the resource identified by the UR

Comment: Alright, so then should I use a `POST` to "create" the new instance, return the id of the new resource, then `GET` it, or can it be returned by `POST`?

Comment: @TK Kocheran, I'm not sure from your question whether it's always the same resource (for which the client would know the URI) or if that reservation is more dynamic. For the latter, you can do a `POST` on a "main" URI, which would return the URI of the reservation resource, where you could do `GET` (to get some status info, for example), `DELETE` (or whatever other action needs to be done).

Comment: @TK Kocheran - Post should be used to extend an existing resource and Put for replacing the state of a resource. In your case, consider the Post to be updating a list of Reservations and returning the URI of the new resource (not just the I'd). Put can be used for changing the state associated with the resource identified by the URI

Comment: Ok, so complete process would be to send a blank `POST` to create a new reservation, the `POST` will return a URI to the resource, then send a `GET` to get that resource?

Comment: No, send a Post with the complete external state of the resource to the container resource, it creates the resource and returns a Location header with the URI of the resource which can then be used by Put, Get for further operations.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but your reservation of the object should be with a PUT; you're PUTting a reservation on the object, i.e. changing the underlying object.

PUT is the right verb here, since you know what resource you're modifying, and it should be idempotent for multiple requests.

Comment: The client should only be using a `PUT` if it already knows the URI of the (presumably) unique reservation resource. It can be achieved if the server give it to the client or tells the client how to form the URI (perhaps via a UUID or something similar).

Comment: @Bruno: Given the fact that it's a reservation and there's assumed to be a single one on a given resource, I would assume it could be as simple as {resource}/reservation.  The server doesn't need to somehow assign a generated identifier to a unique resource.

Comment: sure (I guess it depends on whether you know in advance which resource is going to be reserved), but `PUT` is specifically about [storing the representation enclosed in the request into the resource](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6). That's not necessarily the way it's going to work here. Idempotence is only secondary to that.